# Exchange 2013 database lost

Tags: exchange-server

One of the disks of our exchange 2013 server just crashed. I can recover the mailboxes of the database it contained, but how or where I do it? In the database list it appears the one that is in the disk not working.
Should I create a new database in another disk? If I should do it, how can i move the mailbox to the new database and then import the pst that I have as backup?
I created a new database and then tried to move the mailbox, but nothing happened.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
Instead of trying to move the mailbox to another database from the manager website, thing that cannot be done as the previous database is lost, one can do this that works:

```
Get-Mailbox -Database DB01 | Set-Mailbox -Database DB01-new
```

and then recover the pst in the moved mailboxes of the new database.